# Get the value from only selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to get the value from a checkbox using javascript.
I want only one checkbox value to be passed to the javascript function, and if multiple are selected, an alert box informing that only one box can be checked for the function.
I've tried this:

```
var publish_trigger = document.querySelector("#publish_trigger");
publish_trigger.onclick = function() {
  var _posts = document.getElementsByName('post_id[]');
  var check = _posts.checked;
  var boxes = _posts.length;
  var txt = "";
  if(check.length > 1) {
    alert("Only one at a time");
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < boxes; i++) {
      if (_posts[i].checked) {
        txt = txt + _posts[i].value + " "
      }
    }
  }
  alert(txt);
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using radio buttons instead?

Comment: @DanielBrockman Its for use on a data grid table, the checkboxes also serves as means for identifying posts for deletion and other functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
var _posts = document.getElementsByName('post_id[]');
var check = _posts.checked;
```

`getElementsByName()` returns a NodeList (effectively an array) of elements, so your variable `_posts` doesn't have a `checked` property. You need to loop through `_posts` to count the checked property on the individual elements within `_posts`.

You already have a for loop so add the validation in there:

```
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < boxes; i++) {
   if (_posts[i].checked) {
      if (++count > 1) {
         alert("Only one checkbox may be checked at a time.");
         return false;
      }
      // I don't know what you're trying to do with the following line
      // but I've left it in.
      txt = txt + _posts[i].value + " " 
   }
}
```

(Note: unrelated to your question, you should declare the loop counter `i` within your function otherwise it will be global and might lead to hard to debug problems if you are using it in other places too.)